# Ignore code snippets in PHP_CodeSniffer

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

It is possible to ignore some parts of code from a php file when it's analyzed by `PHP_CodeSniffer`?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Yes it is possible with @codingStandardsIgnoreStart and @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd annotations

```
<?php
some_code();
// @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
this_will_be_ignored();
// @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
some_other_code();
```

It is also described [in the documentation.](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Advanced-Usage#ignoring-parts-of-a-file)

Comment: is it possible to ignore certain rule?

Comment: @TroodoN-Mike: No, not at this time.  Right now, one can either ignore the whole file, or blocks delimited with the Start and End comments above.

Comment: @TroodoN-Mike: In CodeSniffer version 1.3 you can exclude specific sniffs from specific files (http://www.squizlabs.com/php-codesniffer/rule-based-exclude-patterns) at the level of the ruleset.xml file. But this won't work on specific sections of a given file.

Comment: is there a code snippet for ignoring complexity too  ?:)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52881595/6523409 for newer syntax which allows to gnore certain rule.

Answer (score 36):

You can either use the combination: `@codingStandardsIgnoreStart` and `@codingStandardsIgnoreEnd` or you can use [`@codingStandardsIgnoreLine`](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/CodeSniffer/File.php#L1630).

**Example:**

```
<?php

command1();
// @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
command2(); // this line will be ignored by Codesniffer
command3(); // this one too
command4(); // this one too
// @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd

command6();

// @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
command7(); // this line will be ignored by Codesniffer
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52881595/6523409 for newer syntax which allows to gnore certain rule.

Answer (score 13):

**Before version 3.2.0, PHP_CodeSniffer used different syntax for ignoring parts of code from file. See the [Anti Veeranna's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4306803/6523409) and [Martin Vseticka's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30754545/6523409) answers. The old syntax will be removed in version 4.0**

PHP_CodeSniffer is now using `// phpcs:disable` and `// phpcs:enable` comments to ignore parts of files and `// phpcs:ignore` to ignore one line.

Now, it is also possible to only disable or enable specific error message codes, sniffs, categories of sniffs, or entire coding standards. You should specify them after comments. If required, you can add a note explaining why sniffs are being disable and re-enabled by using the `--` separator.

```
<?php

/* Example: Ignoring parts of file for all sniffs */
$xmlPackage = new XMLPackage;
// phpcs:disable
$xmlPackage['error_code'] = get_default_error_code_value();
$xmlPackage->send();
// phpcs:enable

/* Example: Ignoring parts of file for only specific sniffs */
// phpcs:disable Generic.Commenting.Todo.Found
$xmlPackage = new XMLPackage;
$xmlPackage['error_code'] = get_default_error_code_value();
// TODO: Add an error message here.
$xmlPackage->send();
// phpcs:enable

/* Example: Ignoring next line */
// phpcs:ignore
$foo = [1,2,3];
bar($foo, false);

/* Example: Ignoring current line */
$foo = [1,2,3]; // phpcs:ignore
bar($foo, false);

/* Example: Ignoring one line for only specific sniffs */
// phpcs:ignore Squiz.Arrays.ArrayDeclaration.SingleLineNotAllowed
$foo = [1,2,3];
bar($foo, false);

/* Example: Optional note */ 
// phpcs:disable PEAR,Squiz.Arrays -- this isn't our code
$foo = [1,2,3];
bar($foo,true);
// phpcs:enable PEAR.Functions.FunctionCallSignature -- check function calls again
bar($foo,false);
// phpcs:enable -- this is out code again, so turn everything back on
```

For more details see [PHP_CodeSniffer's documentation](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Advanced-Usage#ignoring-parts-of-a-file).